# GWT + Eclipse - how to refresh static resources such as CSS

Tags: css, gwt

I am developing GWT application in Eclipse in Hosted mode.

When I change something in CSS I cant see it in browser. I am trying full reload in browser using CTRL+F5, restarting my App in Eclipse and no change.

Only thing which helps is rebuild my app using maven clean install, restart App in Eclipse and then i can see changes. This takes a lot of time.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I think there must be better way.

regards,Lukas

Comment: I'm not sure I completely trust CTRL+F5 -- you might try going through your browser's menu to clear out the cache and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: At any rate, the "Restart Server" button in the Development Mode view (it's the two circular yellow arrows) is supposed to do just what you're asking for. But I've experienced the same thing; it doesn't always cut it.

Comment: Reload Web server doesn't work. I am using classic CSS file, but my collegues which work with GWT in different project tell my something about different loading of CSS files using resource bundle https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle . I haven't studied it yet but I will look at it later and I will post some experinces. Thanks for advice.

Comment: As I wrote using ClientBundle is perfect and it solves all my problems. CSS classes have its own java representation in ClientBundle interface and I am using styling like MyClientBundle.style().className(). After change in CSS I can see it directly in browser using CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in dev mode the src webapp folder copied to target only at startup, and DevMode does not refresh it. As a workaround you can use [copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html), that take care of applying changes on the fly.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/gwt-webapp</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use an external CSS file for my app, and I immediately see all changes in my browser upon simple refresh (no emptying cache, server restart, etc.) in both Chrome and Firefox.

The problem may be related to the location of your file. My file is in the /war directory, and I edit it directly. Another possibility is how you reference your file in your host page. Make sure you have a relative path like "/myCss.css".

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve this problem.  I don't use eclipse though (I code with IntelliJ and use hosted mode from my command line Gradle script), but hopefully they should all work anyway.

The first is to figure out where your hosted mode is serving the files from, ideally an exploded war directory.  In there, you can find the CSS file, which will be an exact replica of your CSS file that you're trying to change.  Make your modifications there, reload, modify, etc, and then when you're done don't forget to copy that file and paste it back into your source directory.  I use VIM and switch back and forth.  I'm sure you could write a script that copied the file back over when hosted mode ended, if you were a keener.

The second method (and a much better method), as user1570921 points out, is to embed the CSS in your UIBinder code.  For example, you might have:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

<ui:style>
    .outsidePanel {
        background: #00F;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.outsidePanel}">
    Hello, World!
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In the example above, you could edit the CSS inside the ui:style section, hit F5 and see the changes, then make more changes, etc.  No need to copy files over.

Here's a good link for more info: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Hello_Stylish_World

The third way is to use Google Chrome's Dev Tools (CTRL-Shift-I) or F12 in Firefox.  In there you can edit the CSS inline without modifying your file at all.  Fiugure out all of the right values, add new ones, remove old ones, and then make those same changes to your CSS file.  Then you don't have to keep redeploying to see changes.

I personally use a combination of #2 and #3.

Comment: The author of the question actually advocates using a CSS Client Bundle, not entering CSS in UI:Binder, which I believe is the worst option. Every CSS rule in the app must be written once in one place - any other approach would lead to inconsistencies and require a lot of work if changes are required, not to mention no support for multiple skins.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a line `<stylesheet src="sheet.css" />` or `<stylesheet src="/sheet.css" />` into your project.gwt.xml file.

Regards,

Eddy

Answer (score 0):

From your project/application web page, view page source. Normally an option when we right click the page.

Click the .css file link, which appear something like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Foo.css"
```

in this case click on Foo.css

The contents of the .css file will be displayed but probably not include your changes. In that case refresh the .css text by pressing F5 or the browser refresh button.

If your .css changes now appear, go back to your GWT project web page and refresh once more.

Alternatively using a different browser could temporarily show your new changes but if it too fails to refresh the .css file, then the procedure above will be necessary.